# Estimating the value of an improper integral numerically

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, improper-integrals

My question is how can I estimate the value of an improper integral from $[0,\infty)$ if I only have a programming routine that gives me the function evaluated at 100 data points, or 100 values of $x$. I don't actually have the expression for the function at all. Assuming that the function is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, how do I go about doing this problem. do I possibly use Riemann sums? Note that my $f(x)$ is actually a matrix function, meaning that $f(x)$ actually is a matrix with elements that are functions of $x$. Also, this will be implemented in Python (a programming language) so computational methods would be the best.

NOTE: for those who know Python, I have solved a matrix differential equation using scipy.integrate.odeint which gives me numerical results of $f(x)$ evaluated at 100 data points. The routine I am talking about is one that runs this function for different inputs for x.
EDIT:

I need to add two things:

1. As I mentioned, my integrand is continuous from 0 to infinity. I just don't know the functional for, of my integrand. I can get the values of $f(x)$ for any x I choose
2. I **don't want to interpolate or do regression**

Comment: By "I only have the values of the function $f(x)$ for various values of $x$", do you mean that you have it at certain given values of $x$ and that's all you'll ever get, or that you can evaluate it at whatever values of $x$ you choose, just that you don't know its functional form?

Comment: @joriki As I said, the function is continous,cand yeah I can choose what values of x I want to evaluate f(x) at...

Comment: Then I'd suggest to clarify the question, because if I'd have had to guess based on the present formulation I'd have chosen the other alternative (because you don't actually *have* the values, you have the ability to compute them).

Comment: @AlexS please don't delete your answer, every answer is hellpful for me...

Comment: If you're using python, why don't you use the `quad` command defined in scipy's integrate package? You don't need a mathematical formula, just a python function (possibly, defined as a routine) that returns a real number. Though, this only works over bounded intervals, you can likely use joriki's excellent advice, which you should upvote.

Comment: @MarkMcClure joriki 's answer isnt clear to me..But I will definitely look ilnto the quad function! thanks

Comment: @MarkMcClure This quad function only works if I had a function or routine.. but I only have samples..

Comment: @TanMath When you say that you "can choose what values of x I want to evaluate f(x) at", that certainly sounds like a routine. If you have only samples, then you can probably interpolate first.  Have a look at scipy.interpolate.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't want to interpolate.. and I will probably use quad...

Comment: If you're numerically solving a differential equation anyway, you should transform the function to $[0,1]$ first (see my answer), then solve the resulting differential equation and then apply the trapezoidal rule. The main lesson to be drawn from all this is: Write your question complete with all relevant information before you post it; coming up with little bits and pieces of it in several steps wastes both your time and ours.

Comment: I'm quite annoyed that you didn't tell me about the differential equation even when we chatted and it turned out you hadn't provided all the information. At least you could have provided it then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can transform the integral by substituting some function for $x$ that goes to infinity at a finite value, e.g. $\tan u$. That yields

$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{f(\tan u)}{\cos^2 u}\,\mathrm du\;.
$$

This integral you can evaluate using standard techniques. Of course this only works if your integral converges, or equivalently, if $f(\tan u)\rightarrow0$ sufficiently quickly as $\cos^2u\rightarrow0$ at $u=\pi\,/\,2$.

*Edit:* We clarified in the chat that the problem had been incompletely stated. The function can indeed be evaluated at any selected $x$ value, but this is very expensive and automatically yields function evaluations at $100$ evenly spaced values of $x$. In this case, standard (e.g. Gaussian) quadrature in $u$ makes no sense, since it's better to use $100$ points for the trapezoidal rule than $1$ point for Gaussian quadrature.

This of course kills much of the value of transforming to $u$, but two potential advantages remain. First, the linear approximation implied in the trapezoidal rule may be better in the transformed function (or it may not, depending on $f$). Second, you can handle the contribution at $x=\infty$ gracefully, whereas in the improper integral there's no trapezoid you could construct with one side at $x=\infty$.

This is what the computation would look like concretely (with $x_i$ the evenly spaced values of $x$):

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{f(\tan u)}{\cos^2 u}\,\mathrm du\\
&&\simeq\frac12\left(\arctan x_1f(0)+(\pi/2-\arctan x_{100})\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{f(\tan u)}{\cos^2 u}+\sum_{i=1}^{100}\frac{\left(\arctan x_{i+1}-\arctan x_{i-1}\right)f\left(x_i\right)}{\cos^2\arctan x_i}\right)\\
&=&\frac12\left(\arctan x_1f(0)+(\pi/2-\arctan x_{100})\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{f(\tan u)}{\cos^2 u}+\sum_{i=1}^{100}\left(\arctan x_{i+1}-\arctan x_{i-1}\right)f\left(x_i\right)\left(1+x_i^2\right)\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

This requires you to know the limit of $f(\tan u)\,/\cos^2 u$. If you can't determine that, the next best thing is to use a rectangle instead of a trapezoid at that end, but that would make the error closer to the one incurred by Steven's method, so in that case you might be better off using that method directly. The best way to tell is to try it out and see how rapidly the results converge in each case when you increase the number of points.

Comment: So, do I have to change what values of x I use?

Comment: @TanMath: You didn't say that you're using any particular values of $x$ currently, so how can I tell whether you need to change them?

Comment: To confirm, I take thr integral of f(t) for some arbitrsry t and t=tan u? So when I put in my samples, my values of u should be arctan(x)?

Comment: Am I supposed to set u=artan(x) ? and y=f(tan u)/cos^2 u = f(x)?

Comment: @TanMath: I understand neither of those comments. Perhaps I misunderstood your problem; I'm afraid I'm unable to put your comments in relation to your problem. Instead of trying to guess what you mean, let me express in my own words what to do: The right-hand side is a proper integral without infinite limits. It integrates over a function of $u$, namely $f(\tan u)/\cos^2u$, which you should be able to evaluate if I understood your response to my comment under the question correctly, since you can evaluate $f$ at arbitary $x$. So now all that's left to do is to apply e.g. Gaussian quadrature.

Comment: Concretely, that means finding the Gaussian quadrature points $\xi_i$ (of some desired order) in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$, evaluating $f$ at $\tan\xi_i$ (using your ability to evaluate $f$ at arbitrary points), dividing by $\cos^2\xi_i$ and summing with the Gaussian quadrature weights $w_i$. (Or of course you can subdivide the interval and apply Gaussian quadrature to each subinterval, which may be a good idea especially if a weak singularity remains at $u=\pi/2$ (i.e. at $x=\infty$).)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, would you like to chat about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25686/discussion-between-joriki-and-tanmath).

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope it provides even more info.

Comment: The variable substitution in this answer has in fact been recommended by [Takahasi and Mori](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01436624) as an excellent way of dealing with infinite integrals, after which one can then use the trapezoidal rule. But, since the trapezoidal rule is being used anyway, the [double exponential substitution](http://dx.doi.org/10.2977/prims/1195192451) might possibly give better results.

Comment: Is there a name for this method? is it quadrature?

Comment: @TanMath: "quadrature" is a general term for numerical integration. I don't know of a particular name for this method -- I'd call it "transforming an improper integral [i.e. an integral with at least one infinite limit] into a proper integral [i.e. an integral with finite limits] by variable substitution".

Comment: How can I do the limit?

Comment: @TanMath: I don't know what you mean. There's no limit to be done here.

Comment: "This requires you to know the limit of $f(\tan u)\,/\cos^2 u$." So how could i calculate this limit?

Comment: @TanMath: Ah, that limit. Of course I should have guessed that you were referring to a limit other than the one I'd just written about, without telling me which one. I have no idea, it depends on your function, which it recently turned out comes from a differential equation, which you still haven't told us. My advice would be to start a new question, set out all the required information right away in the initial post, and ask specifically whether this limit can be deduced from it.

Comment: @TanMath, if you must, just cite Takahasi and Mori.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to assume that your last point, $b$, is such that $\int_{b}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ is neglegible. If that is really true, then a Reimann sum approximation of $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ will do fine. Since you seem to have little control over the value of $\Delta x$, I wouldn't bother getting more creative than that.

You should at least plot your data to check that the transient assumption is valid. If it's not, then you need to figure out some strategy to make up for the missing area.

Computing $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ depends a lot on how much you know about $f(x)$. You seem to be able to calculate $f(x)$ but, if don't want to interpolate, you may as well treat it as raw data.

The book ***Numerical Recipes In C*** can be found online [***here***](http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf) and probably many other places. Don't let the C part bother you. It is very readable and a good source of ideas and methods.

I have two copies of ***Numerical Methods That Work*** by Forman S. Acton. The book is badly bound and tends to fall apart. It is very practical but a bit more work to read. It has made me look smarter than I am many times.

Comment: Does these books contain info on evaluating improper integrals?

Comment: @TanMath Yes they do. What makes your problem hard to answer is the lack of details. The best thing to do depends a lot on what you are doing it to.

Comment: I have added more info to my question.. I hope it can help you improve your answer...